# Android Application Parse json data

Tags: android, parsing, soap, android-json

Hello, I have this code I want to parse this data to object now I'm getting a string of anyType

I want to get Description Object  Latitude Object and Longitude Object separately

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxxx/xxxx";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "xxxxxx";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:52564/xxxx.svc/soap";    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(textView);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  
        Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
        textView.setText(result.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        textView.setText(exception.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it seems you are using SOAP than why json parsing, you need to do SOAP parsing it seems

Comment: still if you are taking response as json string than please show the json data

Comment: I would just parse the json soap response into a `JSONObject` then extract the values you want. obviously you would have to show an example of your json for an example on how to extract values

Comment: hi the answer is updated please have a look

Comment: Any more help about that ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse json to objects is to use an object mapper

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    YourClass object = om.readValue(jsonText, YourClass.class);
```

This object mapper is from jackson :

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just use json objects to handle the response.

Here is an extract of code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(envelope.getResponse().toString());
String Latitude = obj.getString("Latitude");
String Longitude = obj.getString("Longitude");
```

Thats if your json looks like this:

```
{
  Latitude: "1.00",
  Longitude: "1.00"
}
```

According to your comment your json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "1",
    "Latitude": 0.369,
    "Longitude": 1.258
  },
  {
    "Description": "2",
    "Lati‌​tude": 1.369,
    "Longitude": 3.258
  },
  {
    "Description": "3",
    "Latitude": 2.369,
    "Longitude": 2.258
  }
]
```

you can extract the values like this:

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(envelope.getResponse().toString());
String[][] values = new String[obj.length()][3];
for(int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++)
{
    values[i][0] = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description");
    values[i][1] = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("Latitude");
    values[i][2] = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("Longitude");
}
```

There could be an error in here i just wrote this up quick here.
But its the concept you need to understand.

Comment: [{"Description":"1","Latitude":0.369,"Longitude":1.258},{"Description":"2","Latitude":1.369,"Longitude":3.258},{"Description":"3","Latitude":2.369,"Longitude":2.258}]

this is my webservice

Comment: im getting error value anyType of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: its possible your json is not valid, you can paste your json in this website to check it out: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: [{"Description":"1","Latitude":0.369,"Longitude":1.258},{"Description":"2","Latitude":1.369,"Longitude":3.258},{"Description":"3","Latitude":2.369,"Longitude":2.258}]

This is my json and still i get the Exception Value of anyType of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONOBJECT

Comment: the last value in the array the `"Longitude"` value is not valid json if i copy it from the comment. Im not sure why its not valid. but if i replace the `2.‌​258` with any other number it is valid.

Comment: i would guess its a string encoding error or something like that. but you can test it on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, you could try sending the values as a string from the service instead of a `double`. so your json will look like this: [
  {
    "Description": "1",
    "Latitude": "0.369",
    "Longitude": "1.258"
  },
  {
    "Description": "2",
    "Lati‌​tude": "1.369",
    "Longitude": "3.258"
  },
  {
    "Description": "3",
    "Latitude": "2.369",
    "Longitude": "2.‌​258"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

as yours json data was

```
[
    {
        "Description": "1",
        "Latitude": 0.369,
        "Longitude": 1.258
    },
    {
        "Description": "2",
        "Latitude": 1.369,
        "Longitude": 3.258
    },
    {
        "Description": "3",
        "Latitude": 2.369,
        "Longitude": 2.258
    }
]
```

create a class for data as follows

```
public class Detail {
    String description;
    Double lat;
    Double longi;

    public Detail(String description, Double lat, Double longi) {
        this.description=description;
        this.lat=lat;
        this.longi=longi;
    }
}
```

after it make an `arraylist` as follows for the `Deatail`

```
List<Detail> detailList=new ArrayList<Detail>();
```

and do the following

```
String jsondata = loadJSONFromAsset();//load data and assign as json string
        JSONArray primaryArray;
        try {
            primaryArray = new JSONArray(jsondata);

            for (int i = 0; i < primaryArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = primaryArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String description = (String) jObject.getString("Description");
                Log.d("Description", description);
                Double latitude =  jObject.getDouble("Latitude");
                Log.d("Latitude", latitude+"");
                Double longitude = jObject.getDouble("Longitude");
                Log.d("Longitude", longitude+"");

                detailList.add(new Detail(description, latitude, longitude));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

now you can fetch all detail data from arraylist

Comment: String jsondata = loadJSONFromAsset();//load data and assign as json string

What i should use here... sorry im new here 

Thank You

Comment: you need to pass the json string here make that method and return json string from there!!

Comment: Can you explain me please how i can do it ??

Comment: please get json array as result.toString() and use it!!